# ctrl-r stopped working

Tags: modeling, mesh

suddenly cntrl-r stopped working, even on the simple cube. The rt loop box works but it is very hard to control and flicks about and multiplies.
I use the short cut all the time. Win 11/ Blender 3.3.1. I cant seem to repair it despite all   answers on the net. Could be my problem and some answers were very technical. I have deleted the program and reinstalled. I tried even to install 2.8 (that failed!) I am noobie,trying hard to learn the program at an advanced age! smile

Comment: Does it happen even in newly created simple cubes?

Comment: Yes, Simple opening cubes

Comment: I mean, deleting the default cube and adding a new cube?

Comment: What do you mean the loop "jumps around" - do you have snapping enabled?

Answer (score -1):

I deleted a cube and created a new one and my problem is solved. Thank you
My son had previously suggested that i delete any new programs I had installed.  I did that too, so the correct answer could be a bit muddy.
Anyway it is working and i am very happy.
Brian